# How to show data in tkinter module dynamically-Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to GUI creation in python using Tkinter. I found a script in stack overflow which gives a GUI in which i can i add data manually. I tried to add data dynamically thus automating the whole process using following code:

```
def insert_data(self):
            """
            Insertion method.
            """
            for l in range(10):
                time.sleep(3)
                print(i)
                self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="Item_"+str(self.i)+str(l), values=(self.dose_entry.get()+" mg", self.modified_entry.get()))
            # Increment counter
            self.i = self.i + 1
```

This insert data snippet gives proper output and even shows data in the GUI. But data inserted in gui shows up after execution of for loop. TO be more elaborate .:
`print(i)` in the above for loop print 0 to 9 in IDLE but during that execution the data shown in the IDLE does not appear simultaneously in GUI. It prints data in IDLE until the loop is not finished and the GUI would not show any data until the loop is finished and then it shows all the numbers all at once.

I want to show data in GUI as it prints in IDLE i.e. for every iteration data should be visible in GUI the as it prints in IDLE. Example: 
In first iteration for i = 0
print(i) will print '0'.I want to show it in GUI as it prints in IDLE. Following is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import urllib
import requests 
import time

class Begueradj(tkinter.Frame):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        """Draw a user interface allowing the user to type
        items and insert them into the treeview
        """
        self.parent.title("Canvas Test")       
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.config(background="lavender")


        # Define the different GUI widgets
        self.dose_label = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text = "Dose:")
        self.dose_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.dose_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.dose_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.modified_label = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text = "Date Modified:")
        self.modified_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.modified_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.modified_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.submit_button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text = "Insert", command = self.insert_data)
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.exit_button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text = "Exit", command = self.parent.quit)
        self.exit_button.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

        # Set the treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview( self.parent, columns=('Dose', 'Modification date'))
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Item')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Dose')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='Modification Date')
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.grid(row=4, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
        self.treeview = self.tree
        # Initialize the counter
        self.i = 0


    def insert_data(self):
        """
        Insertion method.
        """
        for l in range(10):
            time.sleep(3)
            print(l)
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="Item_"+str(l), values=(self.dose_entry.get()+" mg", self.modified_entry.get()))
        # Increment counter
        self.i = self.i + 1

def main():
    root=tkinter.Tk()
    d=Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use time.sleep in a GUI because it blocks your GUI. Tkinter has a better solution, the after() method. Read the docs about after method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `time.sleep(3)` the execution suspends, and also any updates to the GUI. The GUI update tasks are in a queue and they will be handled as soon as the application has time on its hands. And there is no time to spare until the loop ends.

To force the treeview to update you can insert the line:

```
self.treeview.update_idletasks()   # Force widget update
```

after you have added the treeview item.